# storybook solid-js: To globally wrap in a <Router>?

Tags: storybook, solid-js

I get an console.error when I try to pass a component to storybook.

`Error: Make sure your app is wrapped in a <Router />`

It can be displayed normally by passing as follows.

`export const SuccessBehavior: StoryFn<typeof AccountMenu> = () => <Router><MyCmp /></Router>;`

However, this requires wrapping every component individually, so I tried to wrap it in a global, but it doesn't work.

```
import { Preview } from "storybook-solidjs";
import { Router } from '@solidjs/router';

initialize();

const preview: Preview = {
loaders: [mswLoader],
decorators: [
         (Story) => (<Router><Story/></Router>)
     ],
};
export default preview;
```

I found documentation for react, but couldn't find documentation for solidjs.

Comment: For the time being, it will be wrapped in a <Router> and used.
Someone will make a library just for solidjs router in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you could not find, it is the Router's documentation or how to use a router with Storybook.

If it is the Solid's Router's documentation, you can find it on the README page of its github repo and on its NPM page:

- https://github.com/solidjs/solid-router
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solidjs/router

If you are looking for how to use in a Storybook, you can do it like any other component. From Solid's perspective a Router is just another component. Storybook allows you to nest components, create a component and use the Router component as the top level component:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <nav>
        <A href="/about">About</A>
        <A href="/">Home</A>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

However, Storybook is good for rendering and testing components in isolation. Although it is possible, testing components one by one inside a router does not make sense.

Storybook provides Solid support:

https://github.com/storybookjs/solidjs

But you can check this repo for custom integration:

https://github.com/elite174/storybook-solid-js